# R regex: grep excluding hyphen/dash as boundary

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to match an exact word in in a vector with variable strings. For this I am using boundaries. However, I would like for hyphen/dash not to be considered as word boundary. Here is an example:

```
vector<-c(    
"ARNT",
"ACF, ASP, ACF64",
"BID",
"KTN1, KTN",
"NCRNA00181, A1BGAS, A1BG-AS",
"KTN1-AS1")
```

To match strings that contain "KTN1" I am using:

```
grep("(?i)(?=.*\\bKTN1\\b)", vector, perl=T)
```

But this matches both "KTN1" and "KTN1-AS1".

Is there a way I could treat the dash as a character so that "KTN1-AS1" is considered a whole word?

Comment: it matches both according to your needs.

Comment: you mean this `grep("(?i).*\\bKTN1[-\\w]*\\b", vector, perl=T)`  or `grep("(?i).*\\bKTN1[-\\w]*\\b", vector, perl=T, value=T)`?

Comment: How could I match just "KTN1"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To match a particular word from an vector element, you need to use functions like `regmatches` , `str_extract_all` (from stringr package) not grep, since grep would return only the element index where the match is found.

```
> vector<-c(    
+     "ARNT",
+     "ACF, ASP, ACF64",
+     "BID",
+     "KTN1, KTN",
+     "NCRNA00181, A1BGAS, A1BG-AS",
+     "KTN1-AS1")
> regmatches(vector, regexpr("(?i)\\bKTN1[-\\w]*\\b", vector, perl=T))
[1] "KTN1"     "KTN1-AS1"
```

OR

```
> library(stringr)
> unlist(str_extract_all(vector[grep("(?i)\\bKTN1[-\\w]*\\b", vector)], perl("(?i).*\\bKTN1[-\\w]*\\b")))
[1] "KTN1"     "KTN1-AS1"
```

**Update:**

```
> grep("\\bKTN1(?=$|,)", vector, perl=T, value=T)
[1] "KTN1, KTN"
```

Returns the element which contain the string `KTN1` followed by a comma or end of the line.

OR

```
> grep("\\bKTN1\\b(?!-)", vector, perl=T, value=T)
[1] "KTN1, KTN"
```

Returns the element which contain the string `KTN1` not followed by a hyphen.

Comment: I actually just wanted the string "KTN1, KTN" returned. My interest are strings that contain "KTN1" and "KTN1-AS1" should be considered a different word, hence not matched.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! The reason I am using grep is because this "vector" is a column of a data frame and I want to select rows that match the word.

Answer (score 3):

I would keep this simple and create a [**DIY**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#diy) Boundary.

```
grep('(^|[^-\\w])KTN1([^-\\w]|$)', vector, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

We use a capture group to define the boundaries. We match a character that is not a hyphen or a word character — beginning or end of string, which is closer to the intent of the `\b` boundary .

Comment: Thank you! That works as well and the explanation helps a lot!

Comment: I am not sure if I can ask this here, but what if I don't want an hyphen before the word either? Say, if I had a word A-KTN1 being matched. I tried putting ([^-\\w]) in place of the first \\b and it doesn't work there.

Comment: @user4451922 try `grep("(?<!-)\\bKTN1\\b(?!-)", vector, perl=T, value=T)`